# Resumir código en pocas líneas y contemplar otros casos sin usar tantos IFs

Tags: javascript

Tengo un script que necesito resumir y contemplar un par de condiciones más.

Realicé la pregunta en el foro en inglés pero no recibí ninguna respuesta satisfactoria, quizá por mi mal inglés que no se comprenda bien lo que deseo hacer, por eso la formulo aquí.

Lo que hace esta parte que les compartiré es remover la palabra Feat. más el texto que siga del nombre del artista de una canción que está reproduciéndose y unir esa parte que se remueve en el nombre de la canción entre paréntesis.

**Por ejemplo:**

Artista: Robin Schulz Feat. Erika Sirola

Canción: Speechless

**Devuelve:**

Artista: Robin Schulz

Canción: Speechless (Feat. Erika Sirola)

Necesito contemplar no sólo la palabra `Feat.` sino también `feat.`, `(Feat.)` y `(feat.)`, pero me parece de mala técnica usar 3 IFs más.

Las condiciones deben de ir en el `ELSE` cuando no se encuentra la letra de la canción la primera vez (ver código de la función completa más abajo).

Cual sería la mejor solución para resumir el código y contemplar las 4 condiciones?

**SOLUCIÓN PARCIAL SOLO PARA `Feat.`**

```js
// Set currentArtist & currentSong
 let artist = 'Robin Schulz Feat. Erika Sirola';
 let song = 'Speechless';
                       
 // Formating characters to UTF-8
 let Song = normalize(song);
 let Artist = normalize(artist);
 console.log ("Old Artist Name:", Artist);
 console.log("Old Song Name:", Song);
 console.log('');
                        
// convert sting Artist to array
let arrayArtist = Artist.split(" ");
                                    
//find item 'Feat.'
if (arrayArtist.indexOf('Feat.') !== -1) {
    let lengthArtist = arrayArtist.length;
    let i = arrayArtist.indexOf('Feat.');
    //remove Feat. and all the following words
    artistSplited = arrayArtist.slice(0,i);
            
    //final result of Artist without (Feat. x)
    Artist = artistSplited.join(' ');
                        
    //get text removed from artist name Feat. xxx
    let featSongSplited = arrayArtist.slice(i, lengthArtist);
    //join previous text in featSongJoined
    let featSongJoined = featSongSplited.join(' ')
                        
    //final result of Song with (Feat. x)
    Song = Song + ' (' + featSongJoined + ')';
                                                   
    console.log ("New Artist Name:", Artist);
    console.log("New Song Name:", Song)
    }
     
// Formating characters to UTF-8
   function normalize(str) { 
   str = str.replace(/&apos;/g, '\'') 
   str = str.replace(/&amp;/g, '&') 
   return str 
 }
```

**FUNCIÓN COMPLETA DONDE IMPLEMENTO LA SOLUCIÓN**

```js
// DOM control
    function Page() {
        this.changeTitlePage = function (title = RADIO_NAME) {
            document.title = title;
        };
        
        this.refreshLyric = function(currentSong, currentArtist) {
                          
          var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState === 4) {
              if (this.status === 200) {
                 var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    
                        if (data.type === 'exact' || data.type === 'aprox') {
                            //lyric found
                            var lyric = normalizeText(data, currentArtist);
                                                
                            document.getElementById('lyric').innerHTML = lyric.replace(/\n/g, '<br />');
                            
                        } else {
                            // Get currentArtist & currentSong
                            let artist = document.getElementById('currentArtist').innerHTML;
                            let song = document.getElementById('currentSong').innerHTML;
                            
                            // Formating characters to UTF-8
                            let Song = normalize(song);
                            let Artist = normalize(artist);
                            
                            // convert sting Artist to array
                            let arrayArtist = Artist.split(" ");
                                                
                            //find item 'Feat.'
                            if (arrayArtist.indexOf('Feat.') !== -1) {
                            let lengthArtist = arrayArtist.length;
                            let i = arrayArtist.indexOf('Feat.');
                            //remove Feat. and all the following words
                            artistSplited = arrayArtist.slice(0,i);
                            
                            //final result of Artist without (Feat. x)
                            Artist = artistSplited.join(' ');
                            
                            //get text removed from artist name Feat. xxx
                            let featSongSplited = arrayArtist.slice(i, lengthArtist);
                            //join previous text in featSongJoined
                            let featSongJoined = featSongSplited.join(' ')
                            
                            //final result of Song with (Feat. x)
                            Song = Song + ' (' + featSongJoined + ')';
                            
                            //return the new values ​​to the function
                            var page = new Page();
                            page.refreshLyric(Song, Artist);
                            
                            } else {
                            var page = new Page();
                            page.refreshLyric2(currentSong, currentArtist);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        //Error
                       var page = new Page();
                        page.refreshLyric2(currentSong, currentArtist);
                       }
                }
            }
                xhttp.open('GET', proxy_URL + vagalume_api + '&apikey=' + API_KEY + '&art=' + urlencode(currentArtist) + '&mus=' + urlencode(currentSong.toLowerCase()), true);
                xhttp.send()
        }
    }
    
     // Formating characters to UTF-8
     function normalize(str) { 
       str = str.replace(/&apos;/g, '\'') 
       str = str.replace(/&amp;/g, '&') 
       return str 
        
    }
```

Comment: Puedes poner temporalmente toda tu cadena en mayuscula y simplemente compararlo con FEAT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar una función como la siguiente:

```js
function findIndex(text){
  const words = ["feat.","Feat.","(feat.)","(Feat.)"];
  
  for(i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    const index = text.indexOf(words[i]);
    if(index !== -1) return index;
  }
  
  return -1;
}

console.log(findIndex("Robin Schulz Feat. Erika Sirola"));
```

Internamente usa `indexOf()` y siempre retorna -1 no se encontró la palabra.

Forma de uso:

```
if (findIndex(arrayArtist) !== -1) {
   // code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres encontrar cadenas similares a `feat.`, puedes usar una RegExp:

```js
const textos=[
'Robin Schulz Feat. Erika Sirola',
'Robin Schulz (feat.) Erika Sirola'
]
const regex=/(\(?feat\.\)?)/i; // paréntesis opcionales, ignorando mayúsculas

textos.forEach(t => {
  console.log('Texto:',t);
  console.log('Encontrado patrón en posición', t.search(regex));
  let result = regex.exec(t);
  console.log('El patrón encontrado es', result[1]);
});
```

Comment: Se me presenta un problema al intentar incorporar esta solución en mi código, porque al tratarse de una función `t.search(regex)` solo tiene valor dentro de ella y yo necesito que tenga valor fuera de esa función. Mira el código de la función completa, esta solución debe ir dentro del 1er `ELSE`. Y el problema que se me presenta es que luego de obtenido el indice debo usar `IF` para compararlo con `-1` para saber si alguna de las palabras Feat se encuentran o no dentro del texto y las llaves no se cierran bien con la función flecha y este nuevo `IF` ya que tengo un 2do `ELSE` al final.

Comment: Además a la hora de remover los feats. del nombre del artista para agregarlo al nombre de la canción debo saber si tiene o no tiene paréntesis, aquí ambas posiciones dan 13, sin embargo uno tiene paréntesis y el otro no.

Comment: Te he actualizado la respuesta, realmente search funciona igual que indexOf pero con una expresión regular.

Comment: Gracias @Pablo Lozano, me gustó tu respuesta usando expresiones regulares, pero no la pude implementar por lo que te comenté antes, al estar dentro de esa función flecha se me complicó para obtener los valores fuera de la función y el tema de las llaves. Pero lo tendré en cuenta para aprender.